# Mails for verification using Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, google-apps, amazon-ses, email-spam, nodemailer

I want to use node-mailer module to send emails to registering users on app for verification and other purposes also. **I am not sure which transport mechanism to use so that emails I send are not a spam and also get delivered.**

I also want to use the same domain to receive emails regarding support and bugs(i.e lets say on email on support@example.com). I am planning to set-up google apps account for this. Basically I will set-up the google apps account with me being an user and having an alias support@example.com. So can I also set-up an alias with say admin@example.com and send the emails using nodemailer from my app using this email address? But obviously I don't want to store my email id and password for google apps in the code for security reasons. So how Should I do it?

Other option is to Amazon SES, I believe its a good service and would be very useful. **But can I use the same domain name for serving email from AMAZON SES and google apps also being able to host my app?** So how to send emails from AMAZON SES by authenticating SPF and DKIM so that these emails reach the inbox of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Saransh,

You absolutely can use the same domain and email address with both Google Apps and AmazonSES without any issues.  When it comes to receiving emails, all messages have to be directed to a single server (your MX records).  But sending email is very different in that you can send email from many different sources without any issues.

To ensure your messages don't go to the SPAM folder just be sure to properly authenticate all your messages with SPF and DKIM.  I'm not sure how this works with AmazonSES, but it was really easy with the provider that I chose for my email http://socketlabs.com

Comment: Do I need to use a provider? You didn't specify how SPF and DKIM can set-up for amazon SES. Please help me with that. Thats the most important thing I require.